# invalid syntax in the secondary line in the semicolon : E4_Email

Tags: python

when i'm ruining programs compiler :told me invalid syntax in the secondary  line  in the semicolon : E4_Email

```
save ():
    lgin_pass_email_contactnumber_save={}
    lgin_pass_email_contactnumber_save[ E1_full_name: E2_password: E3_re-password : E4_Email :E5_contact_number .get()]=E1_full_name, E2_password,E4_Email,E5_contact_number.get
    f=open("E1","wb")
    pickle.dump(gin_pass_email_contactnumber_save,f)
    f.close
    login()
```

Comment: There are several things on that line the are *invalid syntax*.

Answer (score 1):

- You forgot the `def` statement when defining the function save (should be `def save():` (This could be just a copying error)
- You also forgot the parentheses when calling `f.close`. (Do `f.close()`)
- You forgot to put the l at the start of `lgin_pass_email_contactnumber_save` in line 5 (`pickle.dump …`)
- I don't know what you're trying to do with

> `lgin_pass_email_contactnumber_save[ E1_full_name: E2_password: E3_re-password : E4_Email :E5_contact_number .get()]`

, but I'm pretty sure that, whatever it is, it does not work with putting colons (semicolons too) inside the brackets. Either commas will work or you'll have to look at how item assertion works. (Also dictionaries)

Comment: I could not edit it again after I posted it on the site already written the code was incomprehensible and unclear but found the error and the problem was solved thank you very much